# CSS line spacing issue in Outlook email signature

Tags: css, outlook, html-email

We're testing this email signature in Outlook and are encountering an issue where an extra few pixels of line spacing is appearing before the last line.

This seems related to the way Outlook renders HTML versus other email clients or site. If anyone has advice on how to fix this or if it's even possible.

We've done a bit of research and so far nothing has helped, but we were able to confirm this is not occurring anywhere but in versions of Outlook.

```
<body>
<p><br />
  <br />
  <span style="line-height: 14px; color: #414042; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">FIRST NAME</span><br />
  <span style="line-height: 14px; color: #414042; font-style:italic; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">partner</span><br />
  <span style="line-height: 14px; color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">&nbsp;</span><br />
  <span class="appleLinks" style="line-height: 14px; color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">111&nbsp;Adress&nbsp;Plaza&nbsp;|&nbsp;14<sup style="font-size: 8px; line-height: 0; vertical-align: 3px">th</sup>Floor&nbsp;|&nbsp;New&nbsp;York,&nbsp;NY&nbsp;10122</span><br />
  <span class="appleLinks" style="line-height: 14px; color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">tel: 212.xxx.xxxx&nbsp;|&nbsp;fax: 212.xxx.xxxx</span><br />

  <a style="line-height: 14px; color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" href="mailto:email@websitecom">email@website.com</a>&nbsp;
  <a style="line-height: 14px; color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx">LinkedIn</a>&nbsp;
  <a style="line-height: 14px; color: #2D4F68; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;" href="http://www.website.com">www.website.com</a><br /><br />  
<span style="line-height: 14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; color: #414042; font-size: 9px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; letter-spacing: 1px;">TAGLINE<br />
</span><span style="line-height: 14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Service Name | Service Name | Service Name<br /></span><span style="line-height: 14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; color: #414042; font-size: 10px; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">Service Name | Service Name</span>
</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for CSS in Outlook 2007 was removed in favour of the Word rendering engine.  Does your email render correctly in older Outlooks?

The only way to actually fix the problem is to do it by the old fashioned way of tables.  You should be able to achieve what you want that way, and tables are of course supported by other email readers.  It is a bit of a hassle, but the only way as far as I know...

Comment: See http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2533/a-guide-to-css-support-in-emai-2

Comment: Thanks -- it seems tables is the only option. Just wanted to make sure we weren't missing anything in the code itself.